# Tools to fix surface of model subducting into interior surface

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

So my frustration is primarily that I don't know the terminology to search for a solution on my own, and every variation of key phrases tend to lead me nowhere.

The key problem is that my model has a detailed outside surface, and a simple mirror interior surface. I was using a custom brush to bring up the shapes I wished to texture the surface. Unfortunately, a side effect was that several sections of the exterior wall subducted (dropped below instead of rising), crossing the interior surface. The external layer is subdivided 5 or 6 times, and these sections that drop in are 10 to 30 faces worth of vertices on asymmetrical levels.

My intent was to maintain a .125 scale difference between the two surfaces at minimum.

Can I find out what this occurrence is called in blender terms to aid my learning process, And what methods are recommended for a. bringing the subducted sections back out, and b. Maintaining that minimum distance?